# TeXstudio locale issues with LuaLaTeX

Tags: locale, latexmk, texstudio

I am having trouble running `lualatex` from TeXstudio, seemingly due to issues with some locale settings. My environment is a pretty stock Fedora 37 with a local TeXLive installation (using the TeXLive installer instead of distribution repository).

When I try to run the default Latexmk command (e.g. via Tools->Commands->Latexmk) I get the following output:

```
Process started: latexmk -lualatex -silent -synctex=1 "Document"

perl: warning: Setting locale failed. perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings: LANGUAGE = (unset), LC_ALL = (unset), LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8", LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8", LANG = "Default.UTF-8" are supported and installed on your system. perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Unable to read environment locale: exit now.
Latexmk: fls file doesn't appear to have been made. Latexmk: Couldn't read log file 'Dissertation.log': No such file or directory ---------------------- This message may duplicate earlier message. Latexmk: Failure in processing file 'Dissertation': *LaTeX didn't generate the expected log file 'Dissertation.log' ---------------------- Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk to try to force complete processing.
Process exited with error(s)
```

Note that I have changed the configuration of the Latexmk command to use `lualatex` (I replaced the `-pdf` option by `-lualatex`). The issue does not occur when using `pdflatex`. I am pretty sure the issue is not related to `latexmk` (it just prints more information), but to `lualatex`, since a simple call of the builtin LuaLaTeX command (e.g. via Tools->Commands->LuaLaTeX) results in an error as well.

Interestingly, when I configured a custom user command to read the locale settings (just executing `locale`), I get the following output:

```
Process started: locale

LANG=Default.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="Default.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="Default.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="Default.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="Default.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="Default.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="Default.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="Default.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="Default.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="Default.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="Default.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory /usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory /usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
Process exited normally
```

While all those `Default.UTF-8` entries seem to make sense, the error/warning message at the end confuses me. I have no clue, why *reading* the locale settings implies *setting* something, and I have also no idea, why only `LC_CTYPE`, `LC_MESSAGES` and `LC_ALL` are affected.

For comparison, this is the output I get when running `locale` in a terminal (including the TeXstudio integrated terminal):

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

My current workaround is to run `latexmk` in an external terminal (which works fine), but this is not only cumbersome (switching between windows), but I also don't get the nicely parsed error messages and other convenience features of TeXstudio. I would definitive prefer to build the document via TeXstudio as well.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I have found a workaround by using a tiny bash script:

```bash
# make sure environment variables are correct (especially locales)
source ${HOME}/.bashrc

# just run make and forward any arguments
make $@
```

The last line calls `make`, which eventually calls `latexmk` in my case.

Now I have defined some custom build commands:

- 'user0:build': `sh tiny_bash_script.sh all`
- 'user1:forccebuild': `sh tiny_bash_script.sh all -B`
- 'user2:clean': `sh tiny_bash_script.sh clean`
- 'user3:wipe': `sh tiny_bash_script.sh wipe`

Each command executes the above bash script and passes some arguments to `make`, which then does its thing according to the `Makefile` located in the same folder.

These commands can be executed using the TeXstudio GUI (via Tools->User). Most importantly, however, such a command can be set as default compilation command in the Build configuration menu (Options->Configure TeXstudio) by setting the "Default Compiler" option to `txs:///user0`, for example.

When compiling the project (e.g. by hitting F5), the expected output is printed in the "Messages" tab and the Log is also parsed automatically, so you get a nice overview of all warnings & errors and can click-jump to the according lines in the project - just as it's supposed to work.